# Migration rejected - and now what?

Tags: support, specific-question, migration

[How to create a logical system to run a divination engine based on d&d magic?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/100005/10642)

How do I help OP to get this question clarified and possibly reopened (on Worldbuilding on here, depending what he really wants)? I can't comment or edit on Worldbuilding because it was migrated and site redirects me here. And I can't comment or edit here because migration was rejected. Is there no hope? Is this question lost?

Answer (score 4):

I have unlocked it. Enjoy. 4 more characters.